# Mean curvature, integral vs mean of principal curvatures.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, curvature

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature) the mean curvature is define by an integral of the form

$$
H = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \kappa(\theta)d\theta
$$

but is also equal to

$$
H = \frac{1}{2}(\kappa_1+\kappa_2)
$$

where $\kappa_1,\kappa_2$ are the principals curvatures. I struggle to find a proof though, can any of you prove it or point out any reference please?

Comment: Wikipedia says: "By applying [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_(differential_geometry)), this is equal to the average of the principal curvatures (Spivak 1999, Volume 3, Chapter 2)." Have you checked those two references?

Comment: I don't have the references, this is why I'm asking "something accessible".

Comment: My (free) differential geometry text, linked in my profile, might be useful to you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $e_1,e_2$ be the principal directions, so that if $L$ denotes the Weingarten operator, we have $\left\langle Le_i,e_i\right\rangle=\kappa_i$, and write
$$e_{\theta}=\cos \theta e_1 + \sin \theta e_2 $$
Thus
$$k(\theta)= \left \langle Le_{\theta},e_{\theta}\right\rangle=\kappa_1\cos^2\theta +2\kappa_{12}\cos \theta \sin \theta + \kappa_2\sin^2\theta$$
Where $\kappa_{12}=\left\langle Le_1,e_2\right\rangle$. Integrating 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}k(\theta)d\theta =\kappa_1\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2\theta d\theta+2\kappa_{12}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos\theta\sin\theta d\theta+\kappa_2\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2\theta d\theta =\pi(\kappa_1+\kappa_2)  $$
(one can also prove that $\kappa_{12}=0$, but this is not needed here).

Comment: Is it correct to say that given a point $p$ in the patch then the mean curvature will give the mean curvature (as average) in a neighborhood of $p$?